# Is it possible to transition text-alignment using CSS3 only?

Tags: css, css-transitions

Is it possible to transition text-alignment using css3? For example, I'd like to animate text-alignment from left to right, however, adding a transition property on text-align doesn't do the trick.

http://codepen.io/anon/full/lGDwB

Comment: text-align is not an animatable propery: [Animatable properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties).  If you can explain a bit more (maybe some pics?) what effect you are going for, someone may have an idea of how to accomplish it.

Comment: Thanks guys. Both are good workarounds for compensating for the fact that text-align is not an animatable property.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I found out a way of not only animating from left to right / right to left, but also from centered text.

The trick is to apply a width of '0'.

```css
ul { 
  background: #fff;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
}
 
li {
  list-style: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font: 12px 'Tahoma';
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  transition: width .8s ease;
}

ul:hover > li {
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li>this</li>
  <li>is a list</li>
  <li>of entries</li>
  <li>with various widths.</li>
  <li>hover over it</li>
  <li>to apply crazy css magic!</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q5kLcfkx/4/

Comment: this is awesome

Comment: If you use direction: rtl you can achieve fully left to right text move effect with transition.

Answer (score 14):

If I understand what you are going for, one way to do this is to change your layout a bit and animate left/right properties:

[Working CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BxpEH)

This takes advantage of overflow being visible by setting the `right` of the `span` element to the left hand side of the screen.

On *hover*, `right` is set to `0`, transitioning the element across the screen.

> Note: in this case, when transitioning back to the left, you do lose a
>   bit of the easing as it is transitioning all the way to zero rather
>   than the natural width of the text.

```css
.bg {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.name {
  color: white;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  right: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
}

.bg:hover .name {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <span class="name">Adam</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Found this very useful, thanks. Also, adding whitespace:nowrap to the span will keep it to a single line (which was what I've needed to do)

Answer (score 7):

You can align text to the right and increase the width of the container.

```css
.name {
  text-align: right;
  width: 0px;
  transition: width 2s;
  /* needed for when the name is more than one word */
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.bg:hover .name {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="name">Hello world</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good idea but it doesn't work for me (and your codepen too). I seems it can't do transition from `width:auto`, it needs a px value. Can you confirm?

Comment: @FredK I changed the width to 0 and it works now

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question but I recently had the same issue and found the answers here unsatisfying for my use case.

The biggest concern I have with the solution from dc5 is that it uses the **slow position properties** for animation which is bad for transitions as they require re-layouting and are not hardware-accelerated.

My solution is solely based on `transform: transitionX()` and leverages the fact that **`translate()`** is always based on the target element's width/height:

This is my solution:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.b').addClass('left');
}, 5000);
```

```css
.b {
  transform: translateX(50%);
  transition: transform ease-in-out 1000ms;
}
.c {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: green;
  transition: transform ease-in-out 1000ms;
}
.b.left,
.b.left .c {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b">
  <div class="c">CENTERED TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is to simply use text-indent instead of text-align. You have to do trial/error a little to figure out the number of px, rem, em, %, or whatever where you want to move the item via text-indent.

```css
.tsetup
{
text-indent:0;
transition: text-indent 150ms linear;
}

.tright
{
text-indent:50px; /* adjust me by trial and error */
}
```

So, I can add the `tsetup` class to my element. When I click it, I add the `tright` class. When I click it again, I remove the `tright` class. It does a nice gradual fade from left to right.

I use this technique with the FontAwesome `fa-circle` icon `(content:"\f111";font-family:FontAwesome;)` to make a checkbox toggle slider button.