# Simple CSS3 transition

Tags: css, transition

I can't get transition to work with this code

Changing text-align for left to right. Very simple code.

```
<style>
/* Default State */
div {
   background: green;
   width: 1000px;
   height: 100px;
   line-height: 100px;
   color: white;
   text-align: left;
transition: all 10s;
-webkit-transition: all 10s;

}

/* Toggled State */
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div {
   text-align: right;

}
</style>

<label for="toggle-1">Do Something</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
<div>Control me</div>
```

Also what if i need to display none to block

Comment: Take a look here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235764/is-it-possible-to-transition-text-alignment-using-css3-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text-align` property cannot be animated in CSS, as you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties). Although this cannot be animated with plain CSS, you can use the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/), as I do in the example below:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        var spanItem = document.getElementsByTagName("span").item(0).clientWidth;

        alert(spanItem);
        $("span").animate({
            width: $(this).textWidth()
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

The code above is a sample from what I've written in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fV7h4/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Text-align isn't supported by CSS Transition (like maximgladkov said). There are lots of alternatives though.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

On a small sidenote; you might want to wrap your labels around your input elements.

Comment: Thank you for tip about "labels"

Comment: The link also is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think `text-align` property cannot be animated.

But you can add another element with `position: absolute` and animate it's `left` or `right` property.