# Animating Text Using CSS

Tags: html, css

How do you animate the text position smoothly. On hover, I want to re-position the text from text-align: center to text-align: left.

From this state:

[image: Initial state]

To this state:

[image]

When I change the text-align on a :hover selector, the transition isn't smooth. It just jumps to the left alignment.

```
div.subject > div.subjectHeader {
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
color: white;
font-family: 'Lato', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 1.8em;
box-sizing: border-box;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 200px;
transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.2,1);
-moz-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.2,1);
}

div.subject:hover > div.subjectHeader {
    height: 30px !important;
    line-height: 30px !important;
    font-size: 1.5em !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    padding-left: 10px !important;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle: [Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kAPtL/)

Comment: How do you expect us to help you effectively when you haven't posted the code you're currently using?

Comment: post you html/css and a fiddle.

Comment: I'm sorry, I hit post accidentally.

Comment: Can you please post your html also

Comment: I don't think you can animate `text-align` using css transitions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235764/is-it-possible-to-transition-text-alignment-using-css3-only

Comment: So, is there any solution to this besides css?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `text-align` property is not animatable](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-css), so CSS transitions will not be applied to it.

One possible workaround involves positioning your text inside a div absolutely and animating the `left` property instead. For example, modify your header HTML like this:

```
<div class="subjectHeader"><span class="subjectHeaderInner>Chemistry</span></div>
```

Then animate the CSS of `.subjectHeaderInner` using the `left` and `margin` properties. Don't change `text-align` as there's no way to animate that property. For example:

```
div.subject .subjectHeaderInner {
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
div.subject:hover .subjectHeaderInner {
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

I updated your fiddle with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/kAPtL/5/

Other workarounds are possible depending on what kind of effect you want. There are some examples at [Is it possible to transition text-alignment using CSS3 only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235764/is-it-possible-to-transition-text-alignment-using-css3-only)

Comment: Can you kindly edit the fiddle for a working example?

Comment: Very nice! Just what I was looking for! Thanks but the text is off-centered? Have you noticed?

Comment: My example was meant to illustrate a general solution. You will have to tweak it to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** [Slightly better](http://jsfiddle.net/tqp7z/1/), since the closing animation can't be done with precision (without knowing the text length), I made it simpler but at least it doesn't look *that* bad.

This is an alternative that works pretty well, almost perfect I would say. The most notable trick is using `white-space: nowrap` to play with the box dimensions effectively.

HTML layout:

```
<div>
    <h1>
        <span>Some Title</span>
    </h1>
    <p>some cool explanation</p>
    <p>more explanation</p>
</div>
```

CSS that delivers the magic:

```
div { border: 5px solid black; height: 18em; padding-top: 2em; position: relative; width: 20em; }
div:hover h1 { height: 1.2em; }
div:hover span { right: 10em; padding-top: 0; }
h1 { bottom: 0; height: 20rem; margin: 0; top: 0; width: 20rem; }
p { padding: 10px; }
span { font-size: 1em; left: 0; padding-top: 4em; position: absolute; right: 0; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; }
h1, span { background: green; position: absolute; transition: all .3s ease; }
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tqp7z/)